# Find word in string php and create an action within PHP script causes syntax error

Tags: php, syntax-error

I found an old PHP whois script which I am going to use on my personal page. The script is working, however I want it to show a link to an external WHOIS (for more details). I did a search on Google and on Stackoverflow and found the following information:

```
$a = 'How are you?';
if (strpos($a, 'are') !== false) {
   echo 'true';
}
```

I modified and corrected it (thanks joshua miller) to

```
if((strpos($url, 'com') !== false) || (strpos($url, 'net') !== false)) {
    echo '<div><a href="https://www.whois.com/whois/'.$url.'">Whois in detail</div>';
}
```

So if the result of $url containes a .com or .net domain it will show the link, right? Sidenote: $url is already defined elsewhere, so it's an example here to get the ide.

Anyways, now for the issue. I pasted the above text into the current code, but it gives me a syntax error. I am doing something wrong here, but I have no clue what I am doing wrong here.

```
            if(isset($updation_date) && $updation_date != "" || isset($creation_date) && $creation_date != "" || isset($expiration_date) && $expiration_date != "")
            {               
                $important_dates = '<div class="responsive-table">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2" class="heading"><h4>'.$_SESSION['IMPORTANT DATES'].'</h4></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>';
                    if(isset($updation_date) && $updation_date != "")
                    {
                    $important_dates .= '<tr>
                            <th>'.$_SESSION['Updated'].':</th>
                            <td>
                                <span>'.$updation_date.'</span>
                                <span class="c-date">('.domainAge($updation_date).')</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>';
                    }
                    if(isset($creation_date) && $creation_date != "")
                    {
                    $important_dates .= '<tr>
                            <th>'.$_SESSION['Created'].':</th>
                            <td>
                                <span>'.$creation_date.'</span>
                                <span class="c-date">('.domainAge($creation_date).')</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>';
                    }
                    if(isset($expiration_date) && $expiration_date != "")
                    {
                    $important_dates .= '<th>'.$_SESSION['Expires'].':</th>
                            <td>
                                <span>'.$expiration_date.'</span>
                                <span class="c-date">('.domainAge($expiration_date).')</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>';
                    }
                    $important_dates .= '</tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>';
            }
            $array[0] = '
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">
                             <h4><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> '.$url.'</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                'if((strpos($url, 'com') !== false) || (strpos($url, 'net') !== false)) {
                     echo '<div><a href="https://www.whois.com/whois/'.$url.'">Whois in detail</div>';
       }'

                '.$list_server.''.$registrar_info.''.$important_dates;
                $array[1] = $raw_registrar_data;
        }
```

The line I added is located near the end (line #54) as you can see.

Now can someone be so kind to tell me what I am doing wrong here? The error I am getting is a Syntax error at the line with:

```
'if((strpos($url, 'com') !== false) || (strpos($url, 'net') !== false)) {
```

...but probably the rest of it is also wrong.

Thank you in advance for your help and advice with this. Probably it's something small, but if you do not know PHP or coding in general, than it can be really hard to figure something out.

Updated with the code joshua miller kindly provided as I used strpos incorrectly in this example. However I am still getting the same syntax error.

Update #2
Apparently the syntax error is because I used an "if"-stament in there, it gives me the following error, when I look it up with a syntax validator: PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in your code on line 222 (in the code I paste here it's #54).

Comment: I can't help but wonder if you actually read the tour about page, and in particular the part that teaches how to ask a question. You clearly didn't tried to solve your problem by yourself. Since you know what line is at responsible for your error, you should have checked its documentation to be sure that you were using it right, which you would have known you don't since you tried to multiply the number of needles, something strpos doesn't handle. Doing that verification would have taken a fraction of the time type this question took you.

Comment: Hey Joanne, I understand the second reaction of @ksjohn. You edited the question, after your first question was answered. With your edit you asked asked a second question. Now this is very confusing. If you have a new question, you should ask a new question, not edit the existing one. Joshua Miller now added answers for both, so we would have to revert both question and answer to make things clear again. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking .

Comment: @Roland Studer: IMHO the issue was a syntax error. I did mention this was the issue though, however this was resolved. I only clarified the issue to make it more sense. I never asked a question about strpos, I asked a question about the syntax error I was receiving. Maybe my first post was confusing because I used two "needles" in the example. But that wasn't the main issue. The issue was the syntax error, which was caused by the 'if'-statement. I guess I was the opposite of "lazy" because I edited the post so it was more understandable for others. My bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Based on the full code provided, I think the following might help:

```
    $array[0] = '<div class="panel">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                         <div class="panel-title">
                             <h4><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> '.$url.'</h4>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';

    if((strpos($url, 'com') !== false) || (strpos($url, 'net') !== false)) {
        $array[0] .= '<div><a href="https://www.whois.com/whois/'.$url.'">Whois in detail</div>';
    }

    $array[0] .= $list_server.''.$registrar_info.''.$important_dates;
```

**Original Answer**

I don't think you can add multiple needles (the term you are searching for) like that in the function. Try this instead:

```
if((strpos($url, 'com') !== false) || (strpos($url, 'net') !== false)) {
  echo '<div><a href="https://www.whois.com/whois/'.$url.'">Whois in detail</div>';
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I am still getting a syntax error. I understand now that strpos can only be used for one "needle", thank you for explaining that. I think the issue is that I put the code in there?

Comment: Are you getting exactly the same syntax error as before? Can you post exactly what it is?

Comment: Yeah, exactly the same. So I am guessing the way I am entering the code there is causing it. I tried removing the ' symbols, but that didn't work.

I am no expert (not even a novice) in these kind of things, but maybe it's not possible to use an if statement in there, like I did? Just guessing though.

If it's to much of a hassle, no worries, I will just 'always' display the link in there. It's for private use anyways, but I thought it would look nicer in there.

Comment: Send the exact syntax error (add more info than what you wrote above) and I can try and help you better

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver, so it doesn't give me much information "Syntax error on line 222." Not much else. Probably that's Dreamweaver.

Anyways, I did paste the whole thing at Pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/utahEJAE

Maybe that provides some more insight? It's line #222 (the code which is added in there).

But like I said, if it's too much hassle, no worries. I don't want to take up to much of your time with this.

Comment: Can you add a pastebin of the full error message text, including the text before and after?

Comment: I used an online syntaxt checker. And it seems I cannot use the "if"-statement in there: PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in your code on line 222

Comment: Ok now we are getting somewhere. The position of the if statement is indeed incorrect. Editing answer to something that might help your issue...

Comment: That works! Thank you so kindly! So it's was indeed because of the "if"-statement in there. As far as I can tell, which my limited knowledge, you closed the code and used the code you provded and opened the code once again? Something like that?

Sorry, for asking dumb questions, but though I might not understand it fully, I always bookmark answers for future usage and to learn something from it. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150812/discussion-between-joshua-miller-and-joanne).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strpos($url, 'com', 'net')!== false) {
```

is wrong because it supposes three parameters
use instead

```
if((strpos($url,'com')!== false)||(strpos($url,'com')!== false)) {
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as the needle in `strpos()` must be a string.

Answer (score 1):

that's not how strpos() works

http://php.net/strpos
you can search for 1 needle in your string, not multiple.
For that you might want to have a look at preg_match

You can also make it search for "ends in .com" rather than "has com in it somewhere"

```
if(preg_match('#\.(net|com)$#', $url)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `strpos()` the syntax is `strpos($haystack, $needle)` so having two strings like you do: `('com', 'net')` is invalid syntax.

You may want to split it into two function calls like so:

`if(strpos($url, 'com') !== false || strpos($url, 'net') !== false) {}`

Answer (score -2):

`strpos` only takes 3 parameters:

- whatever you want it to look into,
- the string it should look for, and
- the optional offset it should begin at.

Comment: You've been warned before about rudeness. The initial revision of this answer was inappropriate. Please keep your behavior in check. If you get tired or frustrated, take a break from the drudgery of answering questions and do something else.